# List comprehension in python with multiple if statements

Tags: python, list, if-statement, list-comprehension

I am trying to build list similar to this

```
Position = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
      2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
     3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3,
     4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4,
     5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5,
     6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6,
     7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7, 7,
     8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8,
     9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9,
     10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10,
     11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11, 11,
     12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12, 12,
     13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13, 13,
     14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 14,
     15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15]
```

With the list comprehension like below (with one if statement), only the first 7 elements can be created. How can I add multiple if statements?

```
d = 1 
position = [d if i<7 else d+1 for i in range (105)]
```

Comment: It's not an `if` statement; it's a conditional expression. Such expressions can be nested somewhat naturally: `d1 if c1 else d2 if c2 else d3`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No need for even a single if; just use integer division

```
[1+i//7 for i in range (7*15)]
```

Comment: Nice *math* approach.

Comment: Thanks, this is the most simple answer

Answer (score 1):

Use numpy for creating a list of some value with some repetition, append them together

```py
import numpy as np

numbers_i_want = np.arange(1, 16, 1, dtype=int) #last number not included

arr = np.array([])
for n in numbers_i_want:
    temp = np.full(
        shape=10, # how many ints
        fill_value=n #what int
    )   
    arr= np.concatenate((arr,temp))
print(arr)
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution in the standard library is to chain multiple iterables together.

```
from itertools import chain, repeat

Position = list(chain.from_iterable(repeat(i, 7) for i in range(1, 16)))
```

or use two generators

```
Position = list(x for i in range(1, 16) for x in repeat(i, 7))
```

Or, since `int` values are immutable, list multiplication is a viable solution.

```
Position = list(chain.from_iterable([i]*7 for i in range(1, 16)))
Position = list(x for i in range(1, 16) for x in [i]*7)
```